# Angular: 'ngx-mat-select-search' is not a known element

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the ngx-mat-select-search component. I followed the tutorial on https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search but after I install it and try to use the exact code from the tutorial (https://stackblitz.com/github/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search-example) I always get this error when I try to use the ngx-mat-select-search tag (`<ngx-mat-select-search></ngx-mat-select-search>`):

> 'ngx-mat-select-search' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'ngx-mat-select-search' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ngx-mat-select-search' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to either declare the component in your module or import the module from the npm package with exports it

Answer (score 2):

> I'd definitely try the following steps.

Install ngx-mat-select-search in your project:

```
npm install ngx-mat-select-search

Import the NgxMatSelectSearchModule in your app.module.ts:

    import { MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material';
    import { NgxMatSelectSearchModule } from 'ngx-mat-select-search';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        NgxMatSelectSearchModule
      ],
    })

export class AppModule {}
```

Use the ngx-mat-select-search component inside a mat-select element by placing it inside a  element:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [formControl]="bankCtrl" placeholder="Bank" #singleSelect>
    <mat-option>
      <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="bankFilterCtrl"></ngx-mat-select-search>
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let bank of filteredBanks | async" [value]="bank">
      {{bank.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did. But the ngx-mat-select-search tag throws this error

Comment: Can you update the question with your app.module.ts code ??

Comment: Well it might seem like a joke, but I restarted my PC and it worked. -.- 